# What causes a "Java Hotspot 64-Bit Server VM Warning"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I get this warning:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release

What does it mean?

Comment: What caused it to occur?

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046163

Answer (score 13):

It means Minecraft is using a feature that is planned to be removed from future versions of Java.

It's not a problem now, and when it becomes a problem it will be Mojang's problem or 3rd-party launcher programmers' problem, not yours.